# How to get all bindings visible in current scope in Scheme48 (or any Scheme for that matter)

Tags: scheme, scheme48

I'm doing some stuff with Scheme48/Scsh. What I find rather inconvenient is the lack of name completion (analogous to Guile's (ice-9 readline) or Racket's Xrepl). But before Scheme48 gets completion (if it ever does) I'd like to be able to do some introspection by hand. My question is how can you get the list of all identifiers defined/visible in the current context. If I understand correctly, Scheme has one unified namespace for variables and functions (unlike Common Lisp), so this would supply information about both. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no standard way of doing this. Which implementation do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

You want to introspect environments. I am not sure that Scheme 48 has such a feature, but its [module system](http://s48.org/1.8/manual/manual-Z-H-5.html) is perhaps the way to do it.

You might want the `(interaction-environment)` of [R7RS](http://scheme-reports.org/). I guess that S48 is not R7RS compliant.

Comment: Well, `(interaction-environment)` in S48 returns something like this `#{package 361 scsh-user}`. I guess the 361 refers to the number of identifiers. I don't know yet what to make of this. I definitely need to dig deeper.